# Visual Studio Code and Typescript Types

Tags: typescript, types, npm, gulp, visual-studio-code

due to the setup of my project, I need to have my typescript configuration and node modules in a subfolder. Now Code doesn't recognize the types, I installed via npm @types.

```
root
|
|- core
|- project
|- gulp
   |- node_modules
      |- @types
```

Can I somehow tell Visual Studio code where to find the type declarations?
BR,
Daniel

Comment: Have you tried `typeRoots` compiler option?

Comment: Ok. Wrong explanation: my tsconfig.json is also in a subfolder (gulp)

Comment: Which version of VSCode are you using and how are you including the dependency? Recent versions of VSCode should automatically pick up `tsconfig.json` files in subfolders and treat these folders as project roots.

Comment: @Daniel - Did you solve this problem? I am having the same problem.